# Can Miners spend the data-insertion amount?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-profitability

I am wondering if a Miner can spend the amount mentioned in a data-insertion transaction for herself?
And what is the incentive for Miners to confirm data-insertion transactions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By data-insertion transactions you mean OP_RETURN outputs?

Typically those outputs have amount 0, so there is nothing to spend. But if the amount is not 0, those coins are burnt, and nothing - even miners - can change that.

However, such transactions can (and almost certainly, will) carry a transaction fee like every other type of transaction. That fee goes to the miner who includes the transaction in a block, and is the incentive to do so. This is the same for every type of transaction.

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I mean OP-Return outputs.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. Do you see any incentive for the Miners to pick data-insertion transactions to include in the block? I mean, if these transactions need less computational power for Miners? Thank you

Comment: Miners include transactions because transactions pay fees, period. There is no difference between "data insertion" transactions or others in this regard. The computation cost of including a transaction is absolutely negligible compared to pretty much everything else miners do. Further, even if you'd have a transaction with _only_ OP_RETURN outputs, they still have inputs, with signatures that need validation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the point clearly.